# Distributional limit of $f_n = e^{x/n}$

Tags: limits, distribution-theory

> Find the distributional limit of $f_n = e^{x/n}$.

That means that I have to find the limit of $T_{f_n}$. I proceeded as follows. Let $\phi \in \mathcal D$ be a test function. Then:
$$\langle T_{f_n}, \phi \rangle = \int_{\mathbb R} e^{\frac xn}\phi(x)\,\mathrm dx = -n\int_{\mathbb R} e^{x/n} \phi'(x)\,\mathrm dx$$
where I integrated by parts and exploited the fact that $\phi$ has compact support. From the same fact it follows that the integral is finite (since we also have that $e^{x/n}$ is continuous), and therefore
$$\langle T_{f_n}, \phi\rangle \to +\infty$$

I don't know how to interpret this result. In the other exercises, the result was $0$, which is the zero distribution. Here, do I have to conclude that the limit does not exist?

If the limit was a non-zero finite number, should I also say that the limit does not exist? Since a non-zero constant wouldn't identify a distribution.

**EDIT**: In the sentence above lay my misunderstanding. I was confusing distributions and test functions. A constant $f \equiv c \in \mathbb R$ does indeed identify a distribution, namely
$$\langle T_f, \phi \rangle = \int_{\mathbb R} c \cdot \phi(x)\,\mathrm dx \in \mathbb R$$
since $f$ is locally integrable on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Note that the integral depends on $n$ and can go to $0$.

Comment: You can use dominated convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\phi$ has compact support and $e^{\frac{x}{n}} \to 1$ uniformly on compact sets.

**P.S.** Note that your integration by parts approach cannot help: Indeed, since $e^{x/n} \to 1$ on $supp(\phi')$, we have
$$\int_{\mathbb R} e^{x/n} \phi'(x) dx \to \int_{\mathbb R} \phi'(x) dx =0$$
with the last equality following from the fact that the antiderivative of $\phi'$ has compact support.

This means that the limit you get is of the type $\infty \cdot 0$.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. Even if $e^{x/n} \to 1$ the integral is zero only if $\phi \equiv 0$.

Comment: @rubik If $e^{x/n} \to 1$ uniformly on the support of $\phi$ then $\int_{\mathbb R} e^{x/n} \phi(x)$ converges to....

Comment: @rubik Check the P.S. for clarification.

Comment: I think I understand. Since $e^{x/n} \to 1$ uniformly, by exchanging limit and integral I get to
$$\langle T_{f_n}, \phi \rangle \to \int_{\mathbb R}1 \cdot \phi(x)\,\mathrm dx = \langle T_f, \phi \rangle$$
where $f \equiv 1$. Is it correct?

Comment: @rubik Yes. That is correct.